# Array Size defined by long causing arithmetic overflow

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, arrays

I'm working with sockets and transferring small files like pdfs, docs etc to a server. On the server side I'm reading the socket data and parsing out the file size I'm sending.

I'm using streams so the file sizes are in long. The problem is my buffer is 1024, so the last packet I send is rarely 1024, meaning I'll end up with a packet with 741 kbs worth of data, and the rest of the buffer is full of 0's.

To combat this problem corrupting my final output I calculate the difference in the file sizes, then make a new buffer and only copy over what I need, leaving the junk behind. It works fine on my PC, but it throws an arithmetic overflow on the VMware that I'm going to have the server running on. I think it's using an older .Net version than I am, even though I'm targeting 4.5 on my development PC.

This is the code in question. I've tried using check and unchecked symbols, everything. Any suggestions at all?

```
Int64 resizeTo = (int)(packet.payloadSize - packet.ms.Length);  
byte[] endByte = new byte[(int)resizeTo];
Array.Copy(packet.buff, 0, endByte, 0, endByte.Length);
```

EDIT: The method in question

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try 
        {
            PacketInfo packet = (PacketInfo)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = packet.socket;

            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            string remotePoint = handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();             

            if (bytesRead > 0) 
            {
                string peek = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( packet.buff );

                if ( peek.Contains(hStart ) )
                {
                    // file size
                    byte[] fSize = new byte[8];
                    Array.Copy(packet.buff, 8, fSize, 0, fSize.Length);
                    packet.payloadSize = BitConverter.ToInt64(fSize, 0);

                    // File Name and User ID
                    string[] s = peek.Split('#');

                    foreach (string t in s)
                    {
                        if (t.Contains(@"\"))
                            packet.fileName = t;

                        if (t.Trim().Length == 7)
                            packet.ADID = t;                                            
                    }                           
                }
                else if ( peek.Contains(dEnd ) )
                {
                    // Trim up last bytes of info, buffers set to1024 but if the last byte wasnt that big it gets padded with 0s by the socket
                    Int64 resizeTo = (int)(packet.payloadSize - packet.ms.Length);                              
                    byte[] endByte = new byte[(int)resizeTo];
                    Array.Copy(packet.buff, 0, endByte, 0, endByte.Length);
                    packet.ms.Write(endByte, 0, endByte.Length);                

                    long payloadSize = packet.payloadSize;
                    long streamSize = packet.ms.Length;


                    // verify file size, reject if it doesn't match checksum
                    if ( payloadSize == streamSize )
                    {
                        // Handle completed file transfer
                        FileTransferCompleted(packet.ms);
                        packet.socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sAck));

                        UpdateStatus("Payload should be: " + payloadSize + " payload was: " + streamSize + " for: " + remotePoint + "\n");
                        UpdateStatus("Sending acknowledgement and closing socket to: " + remotePoint + "\n");

                        packet.socket.Close();
                        packet = null;                          
                        return;
                    }

                    packet.socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rAck));
                    packet.ms.Position = 0;
                    UpdateStatus("Payload should be: " + packet.payloadSize + " payload was: " + packet.ms.Length + " for: " + remotePoint + "\n");
                    UpdateStatus("Sending request for retransfer to: " + remotePoint + "\n");                                       
                }
                else
                {
                    packet.ms.Write(packet.buff, 0, packet.buff.Length);
                    //UpdateStatus("Receiving data from: " + remotePoint + "\n");       // only for debug                                       
                }

                handler.BeginReceive(packet.buff, 0, packet.buff.Length,
                        SocketFlags.None,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), packet);
                //UpdateStatus("Checking for data from: " + remotePoint + "\n");                    // only for debug
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
        }
    }           
}

public class PacketInfo
{
    public Socket socket = null;
    public const int buffSize = 1024;
    public byte[] buff = new byte[buffSize];
    public MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    public long payloadSize;
    public string fileName = null;
    public string ADID = null;
}
```

EDIT Rest of Server Code

```
public class Server
{
    // socket protocol messages
    const string hStart = "<<head>>";           // header start
    const string dEnd = "<<end>>";              // data end
    const string sAck = "<<success>>";          // received
    const string rAck = "<<resend>>";           // received, didn't match checksum, resend

    int _port;
    int _maxConnections;

    // Internal event
    ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    // Public update event for status updates
    public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, StatusUpdateEvent e);
    public event StatusUpdateHandler onStatusUpdate;
    // public event for file completion status
    public delegate void FileTransferHandler(object sender, FileTransferComplete e);
    public event FileTransferHandler onFileTransferComplete;

    public int Port {
        get { return _port; }           
    }

    public int MaxConnections {
        get { return _maxConnections; }
    }

    public Server( int port, int maxConnections )
    {
        this._port = port;
        this._maxConnections = maxConnections;
    }

    void UpdateStatus(string status)
        {
        if (onStatusUpdate == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("NULL");
            return;
        }                   

            StatusUpdateEvent args = new StatusUpdateEvent(status);
            onStatusUpdate(this, args);
        }

    void FileTransferCompleted( object payload )
    {
        if ( onFileTransferComplete == null )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Null File Transfer Completed Event");
            return;
        }

        FileTransferComplete args = new FileTransferComplete(payload);
        onFileTransferComplete(this, args);            
    }

    public void SpinUp()
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
        IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, _port);                      

            SocketPermission permission = new SocketPermission(
            NetworkAccess.Accept,     
            TransportType.Tcp,         
            "",                        
            SocketPermission.AllPorts  
        );

        permission.Demand();

        Socket sListener = new Socket(
            ipAddr.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp
        );

        sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
        sListener.Listen(_maxConnections);

        while (true) 
        {
            allDone.Reset();

            UpdateStatus("Waiting for connections on port " + _port + ":\n");
            Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for connections.");

                    sListener.BeginAccept( 
                            new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                            sListener );

            allDone.WaitOne();
                } 
    }

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();

        try
        {
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler  = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            UpdateStatus("Connection received from: " + handler.RemoteEndPoint + "\n" );                

            handler .NoDelay = false;

            PacketInfo packet = new PacketInfo();

            packet.socket = handler;

            handler .BeginReceive(
                packet.buff,         
                0,               
                packet.buff.Length,  
                SocketFlags.None, 
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback),
                packet                          
            );              
        } 
        catch ( OverflowException overflow )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(overflow.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception exc) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Client code

```
namespace Client
{
/// <summary>
/// Description of MainForm.
/// </summary>
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    const string hStart = "<<head>>";           // header start
    const string dEnd = "<<end>>";          // data end
    const string sAck = "<<success>>";          // received
    const string rAck = "<<resend>>";           // resend

    BindingList<string> connections = new BindingList<string>();

    public List<byte[]> buildTransfer( FileStream fs )
    {
        List<byte[]> packets = new List<byte[]>();

        using ( fs )
        {
            using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() )
            {
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Flush();

                byte[] header = genHeader( ms.Length, fs.Name, Environment.UserName );
                packets.Add(header);

                int incomingOffset = 0;

                while(incomingOffset < ms.ToArray().Length)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int length =
                        Math.Min(buffer.Length, ms.ToArray().Length - incomingOffset);

                    if ( length < buffer.Length )
                    {
                        buffer = new byte[length + dEnd.Length];

                        byte[] endblock = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dEnd);
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(ms.ToArray(), incomingOffset,
                                        buffer, 0, 
                                        length);                            
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(endblock, 0, buffer, length, endblock.Length);

                        packets.Add(buffer);
                        return packets;
                    }

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(ms.ToArray(), incomingOffset,
                                    buffer, 0, 
                                    length);



                    incomingOffset += length;
                    packets.Add(buffer);

                }               
            }
        }

        byte[] footer = new byte[1024];
        footer[0] = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dEnd)[0];
        packets.Add(footer);        
        return packets;

    }

    byte[] genHeader( long fileSize, string fileName, string ADID )
    {

        byte[] header = new byte[1024];
        byte[] adid = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.UserName);
        byte[] fName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
        byte[] start = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hStart);
        byte pad = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("#")[0];

        int x = 0;

        foreach( byte b in start )
        {
            header[x] = b;
            x++;
        }

        foreach( byte b in  BitConverter.GetBytes(fileSize) )
        {
            header[x] = b;
            x++;
        }

        header[x] = pad;
        x++;

        foreach( byte b in fName )
        {
            header[x] = b;
            x++;
        }

        header[x] = pad;
        x++;

        foreach( byte b in adid )
        {
            header[x] = b;
            x++;
        }

        header[x] = pad;
        x++;

        return header;
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = connections;

        for( int x = 0; x < 1; x++ )
        {
            Thread nt = new Thread(connect);
            nt.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        //connect();                
    }

    void connect()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; 
        Socket senderSock;

        try 
        {
            // Create one SocketPermission for socket access restrictions 
            SocketPermission permission = new SocketPermission(
                                                          NetworkAccess.Connect,    // Connection permission 
                                                          TransportType.Tcp,        // Defines transport types 
                                                          "",                       // Gets the IP addresses 
                                                          SocketPermission.AllPorts // All ports 
                                                      );

            // Ensures the code to have permission to access a Socket 
            permission.Demand();

            // Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance            
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");

            // Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];

            // Creates a network endpoint 
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = CreateIPEndPoint("10.212.98.71:4510");
            //IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipHost.AddressList[0], 4510);

            // Create one Socket object to setup Tcp connection 
            senderSock = new Socket(
                ipAddr.AddressFamily,// Specifies the addressing scheme 
                SocketType.Stream,   // The type of socket  
                ProtocolType.Tcp     // Specifies the protocols  
            );

            senderSock.NoDelay = false;   // Using the Nagle algorithm 

            // Establishes a connection to a remote host 
            senderSock.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            connections.Add(senderSock.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
            List<byte[]> toSend = new List<byte[]>();

            using( FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\jdy5tnh\Downloads\b3.pdf", FileMode.Open) )
            {
                toSend = buildTransfer(fs); 
            }

            while( true )
            {
                foreach( byte[] b in toSend )
                    senderSock.Send(b);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                senderSock.Receive(buffer);

                if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Contains(sAck ) )
                {
                    senderSock.Close();
                    senderSock.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
                }
            }       

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static IPEndPoint CreateIPEndPoint(string endPoint)
    {
        string[] ep = endPoint.Split(':');
        if (ep.Length != 2)
            throw new FormatException("Invalid endpoint format");
        IPAddress ip;
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ep[0], out ip)) {
            throw new FormatException("Invalid ip-adress");
        }
        int port;
        if (!int.TryParse(ep[1], NumberStyles.None, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out port)) {
            throw new FormatException("Invalid port");
        }
        return new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, without a good code example, there's no way to answer your question correctly. However, it's most likely you have a more fundamental issue here: you think you can write your entire buffer each time you receive data. Even before you reach the end of the stream, there's no guarantee that the whole buffer was filled by a receive operation. Throughout your I/O, you need to check the number of bytes actually read, and write only those bytes to the output file. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on how to add a good code example to your question.

Comment: Isn't your payload size supposed to be *less* than the size of the total stream?

Comment: I'm receiving data in 1024 byte chunks through TCP. The final chunk has an "<<end>>" flag indicating the end of the transfer. This allows me to section off what I need to reassemble the file on the server side.

I've added the entire method, although the question is specifically how am I going to take the sum of the subtraction of two longs and convert them to an int to define the buffer array size.

Answer (score 1):

Changed my approach and solved the problem, but it highlighted another, in that locally i'm creating the client and server on the same PC, so my app works fine. When I have it on another PC in the network it changes the size of my socket transfers, therefore my code stops working. Each time I send a file to the server the transfer grows in size.

First run it functions fine, second run it increases by around 700 bytes, third run it increases again, etc. So I imagine like suggested above I have a fundamental problem in my approach. The server portion is pretty much copied from MSDN, but the client side I just flung together so it's probably the source of the problem.

Thanks all.

```
int result = peek.IndexOf(dEnd, StringComparison.Ordinal);
byte[] endByte = new byte[result];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're assuming that every time you read, you're going to read exactly 1,024 bytes (or a short block at the end). That's probably not the case at all. If you check the `bytesRead` value after you call `EndRead`, I think you'll find that the number of bytes you're receiving with each read varies quite a bit.

That's based on the code that I can see. You've left out quite a lot, in particular the call to `BeginRead`, without which I can't really tell what you're doing. But based on what you have posted and your description of the problem, the above appears to be the primary problem.

You need to split your code so that it assembles a packet and then parses it. You need to continue reading and adding bytes to a temporary buffer until you've received all of the bytes for that packet. Then you can parse the packet and do what you need to do with it.

I wrote a small series on this a while back. See [Reading data from streams](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/10/reading-from-streams-part-1/), along with [Part 2](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/11/reading-data-from-streams-part-2/) and [Part 3](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/24/reading-data-from-streams-part-3/).

Comment: I added all my code. All the examples I've seen use TCPClient. The implementation I took was from MSDN which uses raw sockets. So I'm assuming that socket.send is the equivalent of using a network stream.

My current issue is not knowing how to set up my packets and parse them. I assumed if I formatted them all out in a specific size for the file, then I'd end up with that on the other end. It does work when the client and server are the same machine, but breaks when the servers on another computer. I'll give your blog a read and see if it helps. Thanks.